# AWS Cloud Formation - "Designer is out of date, hit refresh" message

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-cloudformation

I am using AWS Cloud Formation using a template and have dragged and dropped an EC2 instance (as this is what I'm working with). I get the error that "designer is out of date, hit refresh". Why would this be? How can I fix this?

Answer (score 3):

This is not an error. Its basically saying that you have made changes to the template and the designer is not reflecting them yet so all you need to do is click refresh on the cfn window.

Answer (score 0):

They are talking about this refresh button, by the way -- not your browser's refresh:

[image: Arrow pointing to the refresh button in the top right of the editor]

This tripped me up; I kept refreshing my browser and losing my changes, and thought my editor was broken.